# Ruby on rails : using update inside show for REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api, webrequest

While accessing my REST API on rails I encountered that inside the rails console this can happen

```
variable = Model.find(1) //Random id
variable.update(:column => variable.column + 1) //my column is numeric
```

but this, while it is possible on console a cannot find a translation to my ruby API for this exact method

Any ideas?

Comment: Any code you can run in the console you can run in the controller. Can you be more specific in your problem? Can you not load the model in the controller? Are you having a hard time with the routes? This shouldn't be very hard. Also you need to run ```variable.save``` after update or it won't save the change.

Comment: @nzajt you don't need to call update after save. Also, yeah, this question doesn't have enough info.

Comment: @maxpleaner I said you do need to call ```save``` after ```update```.  I never said you need to call ```update``` after ```save```.

Comment: That is exactly the problem, My controller is not recognizing the Model but the console does! I have other controllers running the same instructions for the update and they do work (dont know if it is the optimal way but works) , I have scrambled through the code to find if it is a typo of some sort but cant seem to find it

Comment: @nzajt excuse me i said it backwards but what i meant was you don't need to call save after update. Update calls save internally.

Comment: @maxpleaner your right, update doesn't need save. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to increment a counter whenever someone access your `show` method in a controller. That can be achieved with the `increment!` method from the `ActiveRecord::Persistence` class:

```
instance = Model.find(params[:id])
instance.increment!(:attribute_to_increment, by = 1)
```

Note that the `:attribute_to_increment` has to be numeric.

Source: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21